# What is the name of Goku's mother?

Tags: dragon-ball, dragon-ball-z, dragonball-super

In the *Dragon Ball Z* anime series, Vegeta talks about Goku's father and that he was a scientist.

My question is, who is Goku's mother?

Comment: Idk how authentic is Dragonball Wikia but [it says](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Gine), its Gine.

Comment: Bardock, a scientist? http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Bardock

Comment: @Taladris Hey, if there is anything I've learned from Mythbusters over the years, it's that making things go boom is science.

Answer (score 4):

According to her trading card in the spin-off game *Super Dragon Ball Heroes*, it is Gine. The game is not canon, but is official and is not contradicted by the series. Also, the later movie *Dragon Ball Super: Broly* is apparently canon and uses the same name. I cannot link that, however, for copyright reasons.

Included is a screenshot from *SDBH: World Mission* set to display text in English.

[image: A screenshot of a card selection menu. A card depicting Goku's mother is shown with the name Gine]

Comment: Wait, the _game_ is the spin-off!?  Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Nice answer, but you could improve it by quoting the text from the card.

Comment: @DavidW I believe that the original source material for the Dragon Ball franchise is the manga. So all other Dragon Ball media are spinoffs or spinoffs from spinoffs.

Answer (score 1):

Gine’s first appearance is in the manga chapter “Dragon Ball Minus”, this chapter is included with Jaco the Galactic Patrolman and is also adapted in the movie *Dragon Ball Super Broly*.

Edit : Gine was a member of the Bardock team and was saved by Bardock, and they fell in love and have two sons, by the time of Planet Vegeta destruction she was working in a meat distribution center.

This is Gine in the Movie Dragon Ball Super Broly:

[image: Gine]

> Source: https://dragonball.fandom.com/wiki/Gine

Comment: Because of the other answer I’m aware you’re saying the answer here is Gine but could you [edit] this to be a bit more explicit in answering the question of how the mother is?